# String.replaceAll() doesn't work on some files and strings

Tags: java, string, file, replace

**This is the code:**

```
public static void update(String stringOld, String stringNew, String strPath) {
    Path path = Paths.get(strPath);
    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    try {
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
        content = content.replaceAll(stringOld, stringNew);
        Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("\n\nERRORE: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
    }
}
```

stringOld:

```
IDX=8, Tipo=Auto, Marca= , Modello= , Versione= , Anno=2002, Potenza(CV)=200, Cambio=Manuale, Carburante=Benzina, Posti=20, Porte=5, Colore=gkgdl, Condizione=Nuovo, Prezzo=4500;
```

stringNew:

```
IDX=8, Tipo=Auto, Marca=Maserati, Modello=Levante, Versione=Gransport, Anno=2020, Potenza(CV)=250, Cambio=Automatico, Carburante=Diesel, Posti=5, Porte=5, Colore=Bianca, Condizione=KM0, Prezzo=75000;
```

Output:

```
...; 
IDX=8, Tipo=Auto, Marca= , Modello= , Versione= , Anno=2002, Potenza(CV)=200, Cambio=Manuale, Carburante=Benzina, Posti=20, Porte=5, Colore=gkgdl, Condizione=Nuovo, Prezzo=4500;
...;
```

The string stringOld matches a line in the file but is not replaced with stringNew. If I use the same method with another string and on another file it works fine

Comment: Try `content.replace(stringOld, stringNew)`  instead of `content.replaceAll(stringOld, stringNew)` The first String argument of replaceAll need to be a regular expressions `replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` where as replace expects both args to be CharSequences `replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` Using the wrong function can lead to subtle bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses in your 'oldString' are special characters within a regular expression used for grouping. Therefore it doesn't match.

You can test by pasting your text and regex [here](https://regexr.com/) or other online tools.

You should actually escape your brackets by add a backslash in front of it. => `Potenza\(CV\)=200`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use string instead of regex as source, use:

```
String.replace(CharSequence,CharSequence)
```